# Map just bit columns (bool variables in C# entities) to checkboxes in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following auto-generated model:

```
public partial class Exer_Set_Pivot
{
    public Exer_Set_Pivot()
    {
        this.Exer_Set = new HashSet<Exer_Set>();
    }

    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public int RoutineID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Weight { get; set; }
    public bool WeightUnit { get; set; }
    public bool Reps { get; set; }
    public bool Challenge { get; set; }
    public bool ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public bool Distance { get; set; }
    public bool DistanceUnit { get; set; }
    public bool Speed { get; set; }
    public bool SpeedUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual Exer_Routine Exer_Routine { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exer_Set> Exer_Set { get; set; }
}
```

In my Razor view:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].Name)
            @* <input type="text" name="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Exer_Set_Pivot[@ViewBag.SC].Name"> *@ 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Description:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Repeat Set:</td>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Exer_RoutineList[Model.RoutineCount].Exer_SetPivotList[Model.SetCount].RepeatSet, new { maxlength=3 }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
 @* Need loop here for check boxes and not sure how to do it.  Very old code below in which I am converting.  *@
@*REMOVE ROW HERE AND REPLACE WITH LOOP ITERATION *@    
<tr>
<td>

        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Exer_Set_Pivot[@ViewBag.SC].Weight" name="Workout.Exer_Routine[@ViewBag.RC].Exer_Set_Pivot[@ViewBag.SC].Weight" onclick="CBSelectedValueToTrue(this);" >Weight</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help generating that loop would be appreciated I am not sure how to get the column type from the model, then if its a bit/bool create checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you loop all the properties in your Model -

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    if (property.ModelType.UnderlyingSystemType == typeof(bool))
    {
         <label>@(property.PropertyName)</label>
    }
}
```